# Calling compopnet from variable in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

[image]I use in my vue.js project

Assigning compopnenet names from variable in my vue.js project.
or from an array variable. how do i make this
Thank You.
Note: visual attached

I tried to include this in the project with variables but it doesn't work.
Note: visual attached

Comment: Consider updating the question with your real case instead of simplified version, as it's unknown what you want to achieve. This totally depends on where those box1, etc values come from. In this example you need to just use static imports without variables. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors